# Floating point arithmetic -- mantissa and exponent

Tags: floating-point

I have been trying to understand floating point numbers in Assembly, but mention keeps being made of the mantissa and exponent.

I really have no idea what these two words mean or are referring to...could someone explain it to me in relation to floating point arithmetic, or point to an easy to understand explanation?

Comment: What part of the wikipedia page confused you?  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point seems to have the definitions you're looking for.  What was wrong with them?

Answer (score 4):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point

At the assembly language level, you usually don't need to worry about any of this unless you're actually doing bit-tricks with floating-point. The only case that could come up is performance degradation from denormals - which is also explained on wikipedia.